# How to have QLabel update as various numbered pushbuttons are clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I have a dialpad with numbers 1-9 and 0, and a QLabel above it to show the numbers when clicked(same as a keypad on any phone). All are push buttons. What is the easiest way to get the QLabel to show the numbers as the push buttons are clicked?

For example, if 2 then 0 then 7 is clicked, the label would update in real time with 207. The format of the Qlabel should follow standard phone numbers, 000-000-0000. I understand how to setText for one number at a time, but they keep overriding each other. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `QSignalMapper`. It maps multiple inputs through a single interface and does the sender dispatching for you.

```
   QSignalMapper *mapper(new QSignalMapper(parent));
   for (int i=0; i<10; ++i){
       QPushButton *button = some_new_button_function();
       connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, mapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
       mapper->setMapping(button, i);
   }
   connect(mapper, QOverload<int>::of(&QSignalMapper::mapped), 
           [this](int i){/*here your append code*/});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to connect the `clicked` signal of the buttons to a slot (possibly a lambda) that changes the text of the `QLabel` (using `setText()`). If you want to append to the current text, then just do `setText(label.text() + "new text");`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the signals `clicked()` emitted by each `QPushButton` to a slot that update the `QLabel` text.

**A brief example**

In the parent constructor:

```
connect(qpb1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyClass::handleQLabel);
```

And the possible slot implementation:

```
void MyClass::handleQLabel()
{
    QPushButton * qpb = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); // Find the sender of the signal
    if(qpb != nullptr)
        this->myLabel->setText(qpb->text()); // Write anything you want in the QLabel
    else
    {
        // Do what you want.
    }
}
```

This will do the job.

Of course if you don't want use `sender()` (for multi-threading concerns for example) you can either create one slot by `QPushButton` and do the same number of `connect` (heavy and quite a dirty workaround), or create a subclass of `QPushButton` to add a custom signal to emit with an identifier of the `QPushButton` and get it with a slot for example.

I hope it can help :)

Comment: `connect(qpb1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleQLabel()));` - why are you using the old-style, macro based, connect syntax that can fail at run-time? Use the modern pointer-to-memberfunction compile-time checked syntax. The `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros are (luckily) mostly obsolete these days.

Comment: Beside from what @JesperJuhl wrote: If you dispatch your sender by hand, ensure that the cast was valid. Your code can result in dereferencing a null-pointer .

Comment: Oh you are right, I did it too faster. I will make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

[QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) might better suit your needs in this case if you also want your data representation to follow phone number standard such as "000-000-0000". You can make it read-only, disable interaction flags if you like (but from UI/UX perspective it is better not to, since mostly there is no reason to disallow copying), and also you can set [input mask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) you like. Given your current situation, you can base your needs on the following example:

```
// Set your format.
ui->lineEdit->setInputMask("000-000-0000");

// Make sure that your text would be in the format you like initially.
ui->lineEdit->setText("999-999-9999");

// Text will be not editable.
ui->lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);

// And here, you can use QSignalMapper as other members have suggested. Or you can just connect multiple buttons somehow. The choice is yours to make.
connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->lineEdit, [this]
{
    // Just keep in mind taht when returning text, some of the mask elements might be here, too.
    ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text().replace("-", "") + "1");
});
```